# Can hreflang in XML sitemaps include country as well as language?

Tags: sitemap, multilingual, internationalization, hreflang, country-specific

We have a multicountry and multilanguage website. Different countries have multiple available languages. We have different version of each page for country and language.

From [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/localized-versions#sitemap) I see that the suggested `sitemap.xml` approach is to use alternate links with language spec:

```xml
<xhtml:link
  rel="alternate"
  hreflang="de"
  href="https://www.example.com/deutsch/page.html"/>
```

Is there a way to also include the intended country in those links?
Is there any other suggested way of hinting google of a page specific country?

Comment: shall we create a different sitemap for each country, each  containing different language versions?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can also include the country as well.

If you scroll down a bit on that page you linked you will see:

> **Supported language/region codes**
>
> The value of the hreflang attribute
> identifies the language (in ISO 639-1 format) and optionally a region
> (in ISO 3166-1 Alpha 2 format) of an alternate URL. If there's only
> one code specified, Google assumes the code to be a language code. The
> language doesn't need to be related to the region. For example:
>
> de: German language content, independent of region
>
> en-GB: English language content, for GB users
>
> de-ES: German language content, for users in Spain